# How can I figure out where is best to put my wireless receiver?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, internet-speed

I have recently moved into a town house, which means that my wireless router is on the first floor of the house along with my living room and kitchen. This is fine for the vast majority of things, but my PC is on the ground floor, and maybe a few meters (4-5) to the right of the main router. Even with a wireless booster directly above my PC, I can severely alter my download speed by simply moving the wireless receiver (which is attached to my PC using a USB extension lead) by just inches.

As such, how can I figure out the best place to put my wireless receiver? And is the signal booster actually helping, or will it be causing interference?

Comment: Have you thought about using PowerLAN/dLAN instead of wireless? Worked really well for me in this kind of setup.

Comment: @Aki I hadn't, but a quick Google of the phrase would seem to make it a fairly expensive solution to a problem that I'm hoping can be solved in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

If by "wireless booster" you mean a [Wireless repeater](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireless%20repeater&tbm=shop) aka Wi-Fi range extender, they work very well. Its best placement would be midway between the router and your PC, and ideally into line-of-sight (or almost) of both. It must not be placed near your PC (or the router, for that matter) as it would be useless there -- remember, what it does is to pick up the Wi-Fi signal and regenerate a new one at full power.

These tools are very valuable in a large house, where the built-in router antenna will almost certainly be insufficient to provide network coverage in every room.

Remember to set a SSID on the Wi-Fi extender different as the one on your router, so you can make sure you're connected to the extender's Wi-Fi and not the router's.